# secure erase returns input/output error

Tags: password, secure-erase, hdparm

I've already given a detailed description of my predicament in [my previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785328/issue-setting-a-password-before-erasing-ssd-in-what-seems-like-the-proper-way?noredirect=1#comment1177836_785328).
Now I've got this:

```
sudo hdparm --user-master u --security-erase my_password /dev/sda
```

returns:

```
security_password: "my_password"


/dev/sda:

Issuing SECURITY_ERASE command, password="my_password", user=user

SECURITY_ERASE: Input/output error
```

What's going on?

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title. When you can, just mark the correct answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI: unlocking a Kingston SSD by use of `hdparm`, after setting a user password appears to be impossible.

NOTE: The drive will appear as *locked* next time you reboot after setting your password. Until then, security will only appear as *enabled*.

Whether trying the very user-password you just set, or other variants, such as `""`, `"NULL"`, `NULL` or a row of 32 spaces, either as a user-password or as a master-password, will not unlock your drive, but instead give you an `Input/output error`.

```
sudo hdparm --user-master m --security-erase "" /dev/sda
```

*will*, however, do the job (that's **m** as in **master**, since [in Kingston's case](https://www.kingston.com/datasheets/SVP100ES2_us.pdf) the master-password is apparently NULL by default).

The very same master password (`""`) that returns the Input/output error for the security-unlock command, works just fine with the security-erase command.

So don't lock your ssd unless you really intend to erase it, 'cause it's far from certain whether you'll be able to unlock it.

I've been reading reports of [similar issues](http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/id-1844588/drive-locked-hdparm-unlock.html) and I've even stumbled across a [patch](https://sourceforge.net/p/hdparm/patches/42/), which I have, however, not tested.

Answer (score 1):

The `--security-erase` option presumes a drive that has already been locked with that password.  I infer from [your previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785328/issue-setting-a-password-before-erasing-ssd-in-what-seems-like-the-proper-way) that you just want a secure destruction of everything on the disk.  This is how I do that:

```
sudo su - 
cat /dev/urandom > /dev/sda
```

Now wait (quite) a while for the "out of space" error.  Disk sda is wiped, and very securely at that.

If you are in a hurry and aren't paranoid,

```
cat /dev/zero > /dev/sda
```

will work just as well (really) and be many times faster.

Optionally, run `fdisk /dev/sda` next and use the `n` command to add a new partition, accepting all the defaults to create a single big partition.  But even if you skip this step, any OS install you do next will create the partition for you.

Comment: The thing is I _did_ actually manage to set a password, following [kos'](http://askubuntu.com/questions/604426/i-need-to-run-a-security-erase-tool-on-my-drive) and [Nick Weinberg's](http://askubuntu.com/questions/785328/issue-setting-a-password-before-erasing-ssd-in-what-seems-like-the-proper-way) instructions. I could confirm that by seeing that Security had switched from _not enabled_ to _enabled_ the second time I typed `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda`... So, what now?

Comment: I'd suggest trying '--security-unlock my_password'.  It may not want to do the erase, but maybe it will take the PW back off.

Comment: It's just occurred to me that if you initially did `--security-set-pass <string> ` with actual < and > characters that you may have set the drive's PW to null.  Try unlocking it with '' and NULL as the PW.  Seems a long-shot, but worth trying.

Comment: So let me get this clear before I try anything: `sudo hdparm --user-master u --security-unlock "NULL" /dev/sda`  - Is this what you are proposing?

Comment: I'd try `sudo hdparm --user-master u --security-unlock "" /dev/sda` first.  If that doesn't remove the lock, then try your version.

Comment: both variants returned `SECURITY_UNLOCK: Input/output error`